# Wrong status code after AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have ASP.NET Web Forms Web App project. I have some problems with using Ajax calls in my application.

The general workflow for my request is:

1) I make trivial AJAX call at my .ASPX page using jQuery which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/handler.ashx",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           //proccessing data
         },
         error: function (request, status, error) {                    
         }
        });
```

2) Request will be processed at asp.net ashx handler. And if something is wrong, for example user is unauthorized the following code will be executed:

```
var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
if (membershipUser == null)
    {
      context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
      context.Response.StatusDescription = "Not Authorized";
      return;
    }
```

But when I exanimating response headers it’s returning me **HTTP/1.1 200 OK** with html of my sing-in page in response body.
I want to get my server-side status codes and then by analyzing status code make appropriate redirect on client side. Something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: getVersionUrl,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             //proccessing data
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            if (request.status == 401) {
                window.location.href = "/sing-in.aspx";
            } else if (request.status == 500) {
                window.location.href = "/server-error.aspx";
            }
        }
    });
```

I have this problem with all type of errors I want to handle – 401, 403, and 500. And I don’t want to parse html from response body to determine the type of error which occurred on server side.
I’m sure I misunderstood something very fundamental and general. Please help me with that.

Comment: have you tried firebug to check the request/response status if you manually call the urls?